# Epson SX235W printer not printing to 210 gsm paper/card

Tags: printing, paper

I'm trying to print to 210 gsm card but the printer isn't taking up the card so the print is failing.

I've tried setting the type of paper that I'm printing to to one of the heavier weights in the list it presents me with:

[image]

I've checked what weights of paper the printer is supposed to handle and I've found pages like [this one on the Epson site](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/ProductMediaSpec.jsp?infoType=Specs&oid=-12348) that give the weight of its "Ultra Paper" as 240 gsm so it should be able to handle 210 gsm card.

What else can I try?

Comment: How old is the printer? When was the last time the pick-up rollers were cleaned and/or replaced?

Comment: @techie007 - printer is only a couple of years old. Never cleaned/replaced the pick-up rollers.

Comment: I'd say try cleaning them with some roller cleaner and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the paper was too thick for the printer.

I think I misinterpreted the web site. While at first glance it looked like the paper was compatible with all their printers, they only list the photo printers as actually compatible.

A slightly thinner/lighter paper printed OK.